# Replace specific block of text with an indented block of text

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom text editor, although I am happy to switch to any program supporting regex find and replace.

My goal is to:

Search for any line of text containing the word

```
*group:
```

And to replace that with

```
*page 
    *group:
```

Where `*group` is intended with a tab after the word `*page`.  I then need all the content directly under group to also be "tabbed" over one.

One possibility is to do the following in Atom:

Find: `\*group:(.*)`

Replace: `*page\n\t\t*group:$1`

However, this is problematic as it produces blocks like the following:

```
*page
    *group: GROUP1
    *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
        *shuffle
        ANSWER CHOICE 1
        ANSWER CHOICE 2
        *save: var_1
        *throwaway
    >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
```

But what I need is to have all the content under "group" indented like so

```
*page
    *group: GROUP1
        *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
            *shuffle
            ANSWER CHOICE 1
            ANSWER CHOICE 2
            *save: var_1
            *throwaway
        >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Notepad++ in two steps.

1- Add `*page` right before `*group`

2- Add a tab before each line which is not started with `*page` (Using negative lookahead of regex)

**Step 1:**

- In Notepad++ press `CTRL + H`
- In field `Find what:` put this pattern : `(\*group:(((?!\*group).)*))`
- In field `Replace with:` put this pattern: `*page\n$1`
- Press `Alt + A`

Now you add `*page` before every `*group`.

*Result:*

```
*page
*group: GROUP1
    *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
        *shuffle
        ANSWER CHOICE 1
        ANSWER CHOICE 2
        *save: var_1
        *throwaway
    >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
*page
*group: GROUP1
    *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
        *shuffle
        ANSWER CHOICE 1
        ANSWER CHOICE 2
        *save: var_1
        *throwaway
    >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
```

**Step 2:**

- In Notepad++ press `CTRL + H` again
- In field `Find what:` put this pattern : `(^((?!\*page.*$).*))`
- In field `Replace with:` put this pattern: `\t$1`
- Press `Alt + A`

*Result:*

```
*page
    *group: GROUP1
        *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
            *shuffle
            ANSWER CHOICE 1
            ANSWER CHOICE 2
            *save: var_1
            *throwaway
        >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
*page
    *group: GROUP1
        *question: TEXT QUESTIONS
            *shuffle
            ANSWER CHOICE 1
            ANSWER CHOICE 2
            *save: var_1
            *throwaway
        >> GROUP1_answer = "ANSWER CHOICE 1"
```

By this, A tab will prepend to all lines which are not started with `*page`.

Just make sure `matches newline` option is not checked.